# TypeScript: Conditional Mapped Types and Generic Type Parameters

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, mapped-types, generic-type-parameters

I opened an issue in the TypeScript [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23207) about conditional mapped types and generic type parameters. I was trying to define a mapped type `SubAddsNewPropsToSuper<Sub, Super>` which is kind of like the `extends` constraint for generic types *except it only allows Sub to add new properties to Super while not changing the type of any existing property*.

The question is if it is possible to define such a type. First goes my code example, second is the expected behaviour and third is the actual behaviour.

```js
// defines a type that contains all properties of Super exactly as they are defined in Super
// and all properties of Sub that are not already defined in Super.
type SubAddsNewPropsToSuper<Sub, Super> = { [KeyOfNewPropsInSub in Exclude<keyof Sub, keyof Super>]: Sub[KeyOfNewPropsInSub] } & Super;

class Controller<TModel> {

    constructor(public model: SubAddsNewPropsToSuper<TModel, { Title: string }>) { }

    setFancyTitle() { 

        this.model.Title = "FANCY"; // works
        this.updateModel({ Title: "FANCY" }); // does not work - why?
        const x: Partial<SubAddsNewPropsToSuper<{ Title: "Foo" }, { Title: string }>> = { Title: "FANCY" }; // works
        const y: Partial<SubAddsNewPropsToSuper<TModel, { Title: string }>> = { Title: "FANCY" }; // does not work - why?
    }

    updateModel(changes: Partial<SubAddsNewPropsToSuper<TModel, { Title: string }>>) {
        // merge "changes" into "this.model"
    }
}
```

**Expected behavior:**
The type `SubAddsNewPropsToSuper<A, B>` should define a type that contains all properties of type `B` **exactly** as they are defined in `B` even if type `A` defines the same property with a different type (e.g. changes the type of a property from `string` to `"OnlyThisString"`).
The idea behind this is to circumvent the "problem" if `Controller` was defined as `class Controller<TModel extends { Title: string }>{ ... }` in which case `TModel` might actually change the type of property `Title`.

**Actual behavior:**
It works as expected if `A` and `B` are both non-generic types but it does not work if `A` is a generic type.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0A%2F%2F%20defines%20a%20type%20that%20contains%20all%20properties%20of%20Super%20exactly%20as%20they%20are%20defined%20in%20Super%0A%2F%2F%20and%20all%20properties%20of%20Sub%20that%20are%20not%20already%20defined%20in%20Super.%0Atype%20SubAddsNewPropsToSuper%3CSub%2C%20Super%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BKeyOfNewPropsInSub%20in%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20Sub%2C%20keyof%20Super%3E%5D%3A%20Sub%5BKeyOfNewPropsInSub%5D%20%7D%20%26%20Super%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Controller%3CTModel%3E%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20model%3A%20SubAddsNewPropsToSuper%3CTModel%2C%20%7B%20Title%3A%20string%20%7D%3E)%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20setFancyTitle()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.model.Title%20%3D%20%22FANCY%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.updateModel(%7B%20Title%3A%20%22FANCY%22%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20does%20not%20work%20-%20why%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20x%3A%20Partial%3CSubAddsNewPropsToSuper%3C%7B%20Title%3A%20%22Foo%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20Title%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20Title%3A%20%22FANCY%22%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20y%3A%20Partial%3CSubAddsNewPropsToSuper%3CTModel%2C%20%7B%20Title%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20Title%3A%20%22FANCY%22%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20does%20not%20work%20-%20why%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20updateModel(changes%3A%20Partial%3CSubAddsNewPropsToSuper%3CTModel%2C%20%7B%20Title%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20merge%20%22changes%22%20into%20%22this.model%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: I don't know why this will not work, but I am unsure what problem you are trying to solve. In the extends version the subclasses can only specify a more restrictive compatible type (or any which may be an issue) which should be fine for the base class.

Comment: I want to define a base class `Controller` that has a reference to a generic model that "extends" a base model (here `{ Title: string }`). The `Controller` should provide the `updateModel(...)` method that merges a partial model into the current model (like React's `setState(...)`. The `Controller` also implements some methods itself (here `setFancyTitle()`) that should use `updateModel(...)`. The `extends` keyword won't work here since `Title` may be more restrictive (e.g. `{ Title: "Restricted Title" }`).